# Can you enable option+click for right clicking in boot camp?

Tags: windows-7, mac, boot-camp, right-click

I am running Windows 7 on a Mac via bootcamp.

I find the double finger press right click very frustrating (it works fine in OSX) because it comes up when I don't want it to. Especially when trying to use scroll bars.

I looked at the Boot Camp settings in the Control Panel and their is an option to turn off 2 finger right click. However, when I turn it off, there is no other way for me to right click.

I tried option+click and it does not work. Can it be enabled or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly option+click, but if you are using the BootCamp Lion drivers, shift+F10 should work.  Again, this is not exactly a natural click/keystroke.  I'll keep looking around for some more suggestions!